# Applying Cross validation in Naive bayes

Tags: python, machine-learning, naivebayes

My dataset is Spam and Ham Filipino Message
[image]

I divided my dataset into 60% training, 20% testing and 20%validation

#### Split data into testing, training and Validation

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


data['label'] = (data['label'].replace({'ham'  : 0,
                                         'spam' : 1}))
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data['message'], 
                                                        data['label'], test_size=0.2, random_state=1)
    
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.25, random_state=1) # 0.25 x 0.8 = 0.2 
print('Total: {} rows'.format(data.shape[0]))
print('Train: {} rows'.format(X_train.shape[0]))
print(' Test: {} rows'.format(X_test.shape[0]))
print(' Validation: {} rows'.format(X_val.shape[0]))
```

#### Train a MultinomialNB from sklearn

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import numpy as np
naive_bayes = MultinomialNB().fit(train_data,
                                  y_train)
predictions = naive_bayes.predict(test_data)
```

#### Evaluate the Model

```
from sklearn.metrics import (accuracy_score, 
                             precision_score,
                             recall_score, 
                             f1_score)
accuracy_score = accuracy_score(y_test,
                                predictions)
precision_score = precision_score(y_test,
                                  predictions)
recall_score = recall_score(y_test,
                            predictions)
f1_score = f1_score(y_test,
                    predictions)
```

My problem is in Validation. The error says

```
warnings.warn("Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test"
```

this is how I code my validation, don't know if I'm doing the right thing"

```
 from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
    
    mnb = MultinomialNB()
    scores = cross_val_score(mnb,X_val,y_val, cv = 10, scoring='accuracy')
    
    print('Cross-validation scores:{}'.format(scores))
```

Comment: Can you show an example of how `data['message']` and `data['label']` look?

Comment: my dataset? @user2246849

Comment: Yes just to have an idea of what you are inputting into the model.

Comment: I edited my Post to add how my dataset look.

Comment: It's not an error but a warning, simply warning you that the model failed to fit to at least some of the CV folds (you don't show the full message - please edit accordingly).

Comment: then what to do? @desertnaut? can you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not get any error or warning. Maybe it can be worked.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import (accuracy_score, 
                             precision_score,
                             recall_score, 
                             f1_score)
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jeffprosise/Machine-Learning/master/Data/ham-spam.csv")

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 2), stop_words='english')
x = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['Text'])
y = df['IsSpam']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)    
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.25, random_state=1) # 0.25 x 0.8 = 0.2 

print('Total: {} rows'.format(data.shape[0]))
print('Train: {} rows'.format(X_train.shape[0]))
print(' Test: {} rows'.format(X_test.shape[0]))
print(' Validation: {} rows'.format(X_val.shape[0]))

naive_bayes = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = naive_bayes.predict(X_test)

accuracy_score = accuracy_score(y_test,predictions)
precision_score = precision_score(y_test, predictions)
recall_score = recall_score(y_test, predictions)
f1_score = f1_score(y_test, predictions)

mnb = MultinomialNB()
scores = cross_val_score(mnb,X_val,y_val, cv = 10, scoring='accuracy')
print('Cross-validation scores:{}'.format(scores))
```

Result:

```
Total: 1000 rows
Train: 600 rows
 Test: 200 rows
 Validation: 200 rows
Cross-validation scores:[1.   0.95 0.85 1.   1.   0.9  0.9  0.8  0.9  0.9 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, it is worth noting that because it's called cross validation doesn't mean you have to use a **validation set** as you have done in your code, to do the crossval. There are a number of reasons why you would perform cross validation which include:

- Ensuring that all your dataset is used in training as well as evaluating the performance of your model
- To perform hyperparameter tuning.

Hence, your case here lean toward the first use case. As such you don't need to first perform a split of `train, val, and test`. Instead you can perform the 10-fold cross validation on your entire dataset.

If you are doing hyparameterization, then you can have a hold-out set of say 30% and use the remaining 70% for cross validation. Once the best parameters have been determined, you can then use the hold-out set to perform an evaluation of the model with the best parameters.

Some refs:

https://towardsdatascience.com/5-reasons-why-you-should-use-cross-validation-in-your-data-science-project-8163311a1e79

https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/11/top-7-cross-validation-techniques-with-python-code/

https://towardsdatascience.com/train-test-split-and-cross-validation-in-python-80b61beca4b6